# Why is this election summary in past tense even before an election has started?

Tags: bug, election, wording

An [election will be held in a couple weeks on Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/election/4). Near the bottom of the main content is an `<aside>` using past tense wording:

> > 17,568 voters were eligible, 0 visited the site during the election, 0 visited the election page, and 0 voted

> This election has not started yet.

[image: screenshot of the aside element]

Yet the election has not even started. Can it use present tense verbs instead of past tense verbs?

[image: animated gif from BBT]

[animated gif source: getyarn.io](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/3eb9f237-df1d-43c5-9cdc-b953e1a9a5a2/gif) from [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=NiylEdcIZ2Q)

Comment: It could just mean 17,568 voters were eligible at last checkup for 300 repz.

Comment: Or it could be because we all live in a simulation and the elections were already held?

Comment: @Laf Now all we need is the system to tell us who won.

Comment: @Laf - 100%. This *should* be posted as the (accepted) answer

Comment: No repro for me, the <aside> is blank. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXWWu.png). Can you please also share screenshot showing what you mean? Or perhaps it's showing only if you're eligible to vote/nominate? (You can verify by viewing while logged out, or guest mode of the browser)

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda I have added a screenshot. That is interesting - I do see the empty element in a private/incognito window... `<aside class="d-flex fd-column s-notice s-notice__info fs-body3 gsy gs8" role="status"></aside>`

Comment: So it's showing either to mods only, or users with enough rep to vote or nominate themselves, if you have sock with enough rep you can test it as well. ;)

Comment: It's not "enough rep to vote or nominate themselves" (I have 323 and see the empty aside), so I assume it's moderators only. Might be part of the "moderators ignore permissions checks" thing: someone thought this information is useful for a moderator to see, and just made it available without checking the message's wording?

Comment: The one on SO says "_Nominations close in 7 days._". I can't reproduce the behavior reported on Code Review. I presume they fixed some kind of buggy condition that was coded for this specific part of the page. Are there any other SE communities with elections coming soon?

Comment: Can confirm those stats are only shown to moderators until the election has been completed or cancelled. They also appear in a different place (below the list of users elected) once the election is over.

Comment: @animuson interesting - in general should such information be kept private? if so, then perhaps a warning is warranted, similar to the warnings in other places.